# What does the verb "realize" mean here?

Tags: meaning, verbs

Grade of Basic Learning Skill Test which measures abstract thinking powers of candidates is a type of grade that universities use as base for student admission. The grades that candidates take from type of this test are calculated and admissions are **realized** to undergraduate and graduate departments according to grade ranking.

Comment: I have not seen the word **realise** used in this sense before, to mean admitted to / accepted by/. It's not idiomatic. Some Latin languages use the translated form of **realise** to mean ** to happen, to take place**. It sounds like a direct translation into English.

Comment: The site from which the example comes is https://tdakademi.com/service/yos/ - it has numerous errors, of which "realize" is one.